# warning message after uprgraded to drupal 6.38

Tags: 6, security, upgrading, version-control

I upgraded drupal 6.2 to drupal 6.38 to apply the security patch to ignore the vulnerabilities as mentioned in https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6.38-release-notes .

But after updating to 6.38 when i checked the status report am getting the following result .
[image]

How could i resolve this ? is there need to install any additional modules to ignore this warning ?

**UPDATE**

After enabling the module i got this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[`system_requirements`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.install/function/system_requirements/6.x) will raise this warning if the core Update status  module is not installed.

To 'fix', enable the core Update status module.

Comment: i have only 'update status' module and after enabling that i still have that error symbol on , stating **No information is available about potential new releases for currently installed modules and themes. To check for updates, you may need to run cron or you can check manually. Please note that checking for available updates can take a long time, so please be patient.** I run the cron too , is that symbol is native ?

Comment: Native to what...?

Comment: Native means i mean it shows by default ?

Comment: That's a different error message. Slightly related, but not really. No it's not shown by default, only when the requirement fails. It probably means your cron hasn't run in a while